# ClassNotFoundException trying to run "lein run server-headless" for any project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm in the process of trying to learn clojure, but most of the tutorials and sample code that I look at all fails to run for me.

Whenever I try to start a ring app with "lein ring server-headless", it downloads all the dependencies, then dies with a big stacktrace, as it can't find leiningen.core.project$reduce_repo_step:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: leiningen.core.project$reduce_repo_step, compiling:(/tmp/form-init4519196078572752752.clj:1)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6958)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6912)
at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:283)
at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:288)
at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:316)
at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:349)
```

Examples of code where this happens are the samples/tutorials at https://github.com/kendru/restful-clojure and https://github.com/diamondap/ring-sample

Is something wrong with my leiningen/clojure local setup? I'm using leiningen 2.6.0 on linux mint.

Comment: Does the project start if you run lein repl?

Comment: Yes, it does. Turns out that downgrading to lein 2.5.3 fixed the issue. Is this just a bug between lein-ring and lein?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, there's now a bug report for it. I'm satisfied with the answer "it's a bug"

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2079

Answer (score 2):

The tutorials you linked to seem to be using old versions of `ring`—1.2.1 and 1.1.0.  I noticed that if you make a new luminus project:

```
lein new luminus guestbook +h2
```

you end up with `ring` version 1.4.0.  You might consider using a more up-to-date tutorial.  I've been using [the official Luminus tutorial](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs).

Comment: That may be true, but if it originally ran with those versions for the tutorial authors, shouldn't it run now? (isn't that the point of specifying library versions, so that you have a known-to-be-working set of libraries, even if later versions aren't backwards compatible?) Or is that not the case in the clojure world?

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't happen.  I was definitely trying to give a pragmatic answer rather than an idealistic answer :)